# How to avoid filesort for that mysql query?

Tags: mysql, filesort

I'm using this kind of queries with different parameters :

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `ilan_genel`.`id` , `ilan_genel`.`durum` , `ilan_genel`.`kategori` , `ilan_genel`.`tip` , `ilan_genel`.`ozellik` , `ilan_genel`.`m2` , `ilan_genel`.`fiyat` , `ilan_genel`.`baslik` , `ilan_genel`.`ilce` , `ilan_genel`.`parabirimi` , `ilan_genel`.`tarih` , `kgsim_mahalleler`.`isim` AS mahalle, `kgsim_ilceler`.`isim` AS ilce, (

SELECT `ilanresimler`.`resimlink`
FROM `ilanresimler`
WHERE `ilanresimler`.`ilanid` = `ilan_genel`.`id`
LIMIT 1
) AS resim
FROM (
`ilan_genel`
)
LEFT JOIN `kgsim_ilceler` ON `kgsim_ilceler`.`id` = `ilan_genel`.`ilce`
LEFT JOIN `kgsim_mahalleler` ON `kgsim_mahalleler`.`id` = `ilan_genel`.`mahalle`
WHERE `ilan_genel`.`ilce` = '703'
AND `ilan_genel`.`durum` = '1'
AND `ilan_genel`.`kategori` = '1'
AND `ilan_genel`.`tip` = '9'
ORDER BY `ilan_genel`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 225 , 15
```

and this is what i get in explain section:

[image: explain]

these are the indexes that i already tried to use:

[image: indexes]

any help will be deeply appreciated what kind of index will be the best option or should i use another table structure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first simplify your query to understand your problem better. As it appears your problem is constrained to the ilan_gen1 table, the following query would also show you the same symptoms.:

```
SELECT * from ilan_gene1 WHERE `ilan_genel`.`ilce` = '703'
AND `ilan_genel`.`durum` = '1'
AND `ilan_genel`.`kategori` = '1'
AND `ilan_genel`.`tip` = '9'
```

So the first thing to do is check that this is the case. If so, the simpler question is simply why does this query require a file sort on 3661 rows. Now the 'hepsi' index sort order is:

*ilce->mahelle->durum->kategori->tip->ozelik*

I've written it that way to emphasise that it is first sorted on 'ilce', then 'mahelle', then 'durum', etc. Note that your query does not specify the 'mahelle' value. So the best the index can do is lookup on 'ilce'. Now I don't know the heuristics of your data, but the next logical step in debugging this would be:

```
SELECT * from ilan_gene1 WHERE `ilan_genel`.`ilce` = '703'`
```

Does this return 3661 rows?

If so, you should be able to see what is happening. The database is using the hepsi index, to the best of it's ability, getting 3661 rows back then sorting those rows in order to eliminate values according to the other criteria (i.e. 'durum', 'kategori', 'tip').

The key point here is that if data is sorted by A, B, C in that order and B is not specified, then the best logical thing that can be done is: first a look up on A then a filter on the remaining values against C. In this case, that filter is performed via a file sort.

*Possible solutions*

1. Supply 'mahelle' (B) in your query.
2. Add a new index on 'ilan_gene1' that doesn't require 'mahelle', i.e. A->C->D...

*Another tip*

In case I have misdiagnosed your problem (easy to do when I don't have your system to test against), the important thing here is the approach to solving the problem. In particular, how to break a complicated query into a simpler query that produces the same behaviour, until you get to a very simple SELECT statement that demonstrates the problem. At this point, the answer is usually much clearer.

Comment: thanks for the explanation but don't you think "deneme" index should cover up what you said on possible solutions ? but mysql engine doesn't select "deneme" index or am i mistaken ?

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour with a simpler query as suggested?

Comment: by saying simpler query are you mentioning removing joins ?

Comment: You are correct though - I see that 'deneme' is considered as a possible index. Usually databases calculate a choice of index based on heuristics they keep on tables to give them some idea which choice is more efficient. The best way to fix this is to present the database with little choice through design...

Comment: ...and yes, what you should generally try to do is create the *simplest* query on one table as possible to reproduce the problem and then try it with different criteria.